# How can i Bind a func to a button and a key

Tags: python-3.x, function, button, binding

I'm trying to bind the `Enter Key` to the `Enter Button`, but if i try it with "event" the function dosn't work, if i do it without the key don't works.

Below are the pieces of the code for this problem.

```
def enterbutton():
    ip01 = input = date_write.get()
    ip02 = input = text_write.get()
    ip03 = input = total_write.get()
    output_label = Label (chart_frame, text=ip01 + " " + ip02 + " " + ip03 + " wurde eingetragen").place (relx=0.15, rely=0.85, anchor=NW)
    chart_frame.after (0, clearfield)
    chart_frame.after (5000, output_label.destroy)

def clearfield():
    text_write.delete(0, "end"),
    date_write.delete(0, "end"),
    total_write.delete(0, "end")
    return None

#Input Button
enter_button = Button (input_frame, text="Enter", command=enterbutton)
enter_button.place (height=20, width=50, relx=0.05, rely=0.7)

#Eintrag-Eingabe
text_write = Entry (input_frame)
text_write.place (height=20, relwidth=0.9, relx=0.05, rely=0.20, anchor=NW)
te_writeL = Label (input_frame, text="Eintrag:")
te_writeL.place (height=20, width=50, relx=0.05, rely=0.05)

root.bind ("<Return>", enterbutton)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a command in python that had been defined it needs brackets after it for example

```
enter_button = Button (input_frame, text="Enter", command=enterbutton())
```

I added brackets at the end

Comment: Hey Leo, if i add this bracketts, then i get following Error "NameError: name 'date_write' is not defined".

Comment: Yeah, direct in the func and these are connected to the Entry Widgets Here is the Code below date_write = Entry (input_frame) date_write.place (height=20, relwidth=0.4, relx=0.05, rely=0.5)